# Problems in understanding exercise 2.2. from Chris Doran "Geometric Algebra for physicists"

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I am currently trying to learn geometric algebra with Dorans book. I tried to do excercise 2.2., but I get stuck at the formulation of the exercise:

By expanding the bivector $a \wedge b$ in terms of geometric products, prove
that it anticommutes with both a and b, but commutes with any vector
perpendicular to the $a \wedge b$ plane.

My thoughts on the excercise were follwing:

a)
$$a \wedge b = \frac{1}{2}(ab - ba) = -\frac{1}{2}(ba - ab) = -b \wedge a$$

b) If we want a vector perpendicular to the $a \wedge b$ plane we can write that as $a \wedge (\lambda a \times b)$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} $. Now we have to show that this is equal to $(\lambda a \times b) \wedge a$, right?

Do I interpret his exercise right? So does he mean the geometric product or the outer product when he talks about **it**, but the wedge product was already defined as anticommutative. I am a bit confused. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are asking about the geometric product. They are asking to prove the following three equalities:
$$
  (a\wedge b)a = -a(a\wedge b),
$$$$
  (a\wedge b)b = -b(a\wedge b),
$$$$
  (a\wedge b)c = c(a\wedge b),
$$
where $c$ is any vector perpendicular to both $a$ and $b$. You should also not use the cross product for anything, for at least two reasons:

1. One of the points of geometric algebra is to do away with kludges like the cross product which only work in 3D.
2. The notation $\times$ is used in this book for something entirely different, namely the *commutator product* of multivectors
   $$
     A\times B := \frac12(AB - BA),
   $$
   though I think the authors do also use $\times$ to represent the cross product when they talk about it, which is an unfortunate overloading of notation.

---

A side note: the wedge product **is not** "defined to be anticommutative". It is anticommutative **between two vectors**, but it is absolutely not anticommutative in general.

Comment: Omg thank you so much. Sometimes I wonder if Doran formulates his exercises a bit strange or I am just not smart enough to understand him 

Comment: So you mean e.g. multivectors when you talk about "in general"?

Comment: @JLJ Multivectors yes, but even just blades. For example, if $A$ is any multivector but $B$ is any bivector (including a bivector blade) then they *commute* under the wedge product: $$A\wedge B = B\wedge A.$$